# JavalibUsb library - getDevice function

Tags: usb, java

I want to use Javalibusb library to connect PIC18f4550 via a USB connection to the PC
I have a problem with the following line of code:

```
  // get a device instance with vendor id and product id
 Device dev = USB.getDevice((short) 0x8235, (short) 0x0222);
```

from where can I know that vendor ID and product ID to insert into the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use [**this**](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/335A90747734097886257070006415B9).

Comment: dev.open(1, 0, -1);
what are the appropriate values?